# mysql join under condition

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I have this table id_name:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  |  one |
| 2  |  two |
| 3  | three|
```

... etc., and another table ids

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+----
| id | aid | bid | cid | ...
+----+-----+-----+-----+----
| 1  |  1  |  2  |  3  | ...
| 2  |  2  | null| null| ...
| 3  |  2  |  3  | null| ...
```

and I want to select something like this:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----
| id | aid |aname| bid |bname| cid |cname| ...
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----
| 1  |  1  | one |  2  | two |  3  |three| ...
| 2  |  2  | two | null| null| null| null| ...
| 3  |  2  | two |  3  |three| null| null| ...
```

Basically, if the id is not null, then fetch the name to the corresponding column, else keep the name null.

In my project I have 7 columns (a-g).

I tried a 7 level joins, basically something like:

```
SELECT id,a.id AS aid,a.name AS aname,b.id AS bid,b.name AS bname, ...
  FROM ids AS t
JOIN id_name AS a ON a.id=t.aid
JOIN id_name AS b ON b.id=t.bid
...
```

etc. But then I notice that if, say, t.b is null, then b.id=null is always false, so I will not select any rows.
How can I do something like IF b.id IS NULL THEN JOIN id_name AS b ON b.id=t.bid ELSE "keep bname null"?

I understand that I can create a temporary table and do 7 updates. But is there a way to use a single SELECT to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result using `cross join` too with out the need for joining the same table multiple times

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce156d/8)**

```
select ids.id, 
       aid, 
       max(case when aid = id_name.id then id_name.name end)  as aname, 
       bid, 
       max(case when bid = id_name.id then id_name.name end ) as bname
from ids
cross join id_name 
group by ids.id, aid, bid
```

Comment: Thanks! this looks much simpler :)

Comment: One more question: actually I have two id_name tables, one for column a,b and one for column c. Do I do two cross joins like cross join id_name cross join id_name2?

Answer (score 2):

You must use an outer join. For example

```
SELECT id,a.id AS aid,a.name AS aname,b.id AS bid,b.name AS bname, ...
  FROM ids AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN id_name AS a ON a.id=t.aid
LEFT OUTER JOIN id_name AS b ON b.id=t.bid
...
```

more info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: I actually use a cross join to finish this. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  i.id,
  a.id as aid,
  a.name as aname,
  b.id as bid,
  b.name as bname,
  c.id as cid,
  c.name as cname
from ids i
  left join id_name a
    on a.id = i.aid
  left join id_name b
    on b.id = i.bid
  left join id_name c
    on c.id = i.cid
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ea82/1

Comment: I actually end up with a cross join. Thank you anyways!